# By pass the first two lines of csv file

Tags: php, fgets

I am trying to read data from a csv file using `fgets`. However, I would want to by pass the first two top rows.

By default, `fgets` by passes the first row alone. How can I tweak this to make it by pass the first two top rows?

```
$myfile = "/home/dibon/AML_Data/test.csv";
$myfile = fopen("$myfile", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");  

fgets($myfile); //First fgets to read over header line.

while($line=fgets($myfile)){
//Explode your line by space delimeter
$words=explode("|",$line);

DB::table('transaction_incremental')->insert(
['ReceiptNumber' => "$words[0]", 'InitiatingMSISDN' => "$words[2]"]
);

}
```

Comment: call `fgets($myfile);` once more before loop

Comment: @splash58, no, that's __too__ easy!

Comment: PHP provides a built-in function for parsing csv files ([fputcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)), why can't you use it?

Comment: @splash58 how do I do that?

Comment: @user6721269 `fgets($myfile); fgets($myfile); while`

Comment: @u_mulder, due to OP's question, It seems not so easy :)

Comment: @splash58 thanks... worked

Comment: @user6721269 did you have doubts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fgetcsv($handle); // get line 0 and move to next
fgetcsv($handle); // get line 1 and move to next
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    ....
}
```